# Google Apps Script installable on edit trigger running without user input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

So I have an installable trigger that runs when a user updates a cell, the corresponding data gets updated in another spreadsheet. (Think of those spreadsheet work tracking apps for inter-team coordination). I have the function for the installable trigger named 'onEdit(e)' I know this is poor practice, I'm learning and will be updating that after I identify and fix this problem, however! Multiple times the execution log has shown the installable trigger running and NOT the simple trigger. It has caused minor incorrect data issues by running the onEdit code when as far as I can tell no edit has been made, as the simple trigger did not run. I have no onChange or onUpdate that runs when formatting or other changes are made. I don't know that my code is pertinent as it seems I'm lacking an understanding of what can trigger an installable on edit trigger? I can provide code if needed however.

I've looked into the installable triggers events that cause it to run however I cannot identify what's causing it. The executions log has the installed trigger running 3 separate times for one user without the simple trigger running, one of the installable triggers runtimes was over 200 seconds when the average is between 5 and 10 seconds. I haven't tried much yet to fix this as I'm wholly unsure of what the source of the problem is. The installable trigger ran as if normal, pulling the users email and attaching it to work they are not responsible for.

I just read through some suggested questions from stackoverflow's duplicate prevention and found that TIME driven triggers seem to have this issue, am I just confirming right now that it's also an on edit driven bug as well? Time driven workaround is saving the last run time and only running if it's old enough, that will not work for my script I will likely have to implement a UI confirmation? Is there anything else I can try?

EDIT: For clarity, the installable trigger runs *without a user making an edit!* and I am aware of the simple vs installable triggers. I am fixing that issue after it's no longer necessary to use it to identify when this bug occurs. The only way I can definitively and easily identify when it occurs however is when the installed trigger shows in the execution log, and the simple trigger is absent.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the issue is that you have both an installable and a simple trigger for the same function and they should both run at the same time, however the simple trigger sometimes does not run along with the installable one, correct?

Comment: Just to be clear: 1) any function called `onEdit` will be recognised as a simple trigger just by virtue of its name. 2) it is NOT recommended to have multiple "onEdit" triggers and/or both simple AND installable "onEdit" triggers (however they might be named). You said that you "will be updating that after I identify and fix this problem" - I'd strongly recommend that you change the name (and re-check the trigger setup) immediately because two `onEdit` triggers are problematic. If there are two events that you are trying to "watch" you can always combine them in a single function

Comment: Only the installable trigger randomly runs, similar to the time based trigger bug. The strangest thing is it has a user email attached, an input value, and a specific spreadsheet edited range.

Also, my installable trigger is set to run my "onEdit" function, it's not two separate functions, they're identical code, but one gets run as a simple trigger and fails due to the lack of permission, the other runs fine. It's a relic of my lack of understanding at the beginning of this project.

Comment: @FernandoLara Specifically to answer your question, yes I have a funtion named "onEdit(e)" that runs on an installable trigger, making both run. My issue is that a user will make no edit at all and the installable trigger will run with info and a user attached. Altering data inaccurately.

Comment: @Bobtobismo is the user doing multiple changes to the file in a short period of time? do you have a screenshot of the execution log showing the behavior?

Comment: @FernandoLara I'm sorry I've been insanely busy with work. Multiple users make changes to the file throughout the day. The script reads the edits, and performs tasks based on what edit was made. I will try to look up the log when this happened and screenshot it. I'll use an imgur link.

Comment: GAS does not keep logs beyond 7 days, I unfortunately missed that window, and cannot provide the requested screenshots.